# How to upload a project with folders to GitHub

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm working on a project and I want to upload it to my GitHub repository.  The project contains files inside of folders, and I don't know how to upload them.  Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install git,
Then, create a GitHub repository and follow the instructions on GitHub to push your code